# What are $\mathbb C$-subalgebras of $\mathbb C\{x\}$ with finite-dimensional quotient?

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, power-series

Let $\Bbb C\{x\}$ be the ring of convergent power series with maximal ideal $\mathfrak m$.

Suppose $A \subset \mathbb C\{x\}$ is a $\mathbb C$-subalgebra such that $$\delta = \dim_{\mathbb C}( \mathbb C\{x\} / A) < \infty.$$ I wonder what we can say about the structure of $A$. Since
$$ \mathbb C\{x\} \supset \mathfrak m \supset \mathfrak m^2 \supset \dotsc$$
is a filtration, there is some $k > \delta$ such that $\mathfrak m^k \subset A$. So if $f = \sum_n a_n x^n$ is a generic convergent power series, there are $k - \delta$ linear equations in $a_1, \dotsc, a_{k-1}$ which determine if $f \in A$. However, one cannot take arbitrary linear equations: We always have $a_1 = 0$, since otherwiese $x \mapsto f$ would determine an isomorphism of $\mathbb C\{x\}$. Also, the linear equations have to be

Some examples I gathered

1. For $k = \delta + 1$ we get $A = \{\sum a_n x^n | a_1 = \dotsc = a_{\delta} = 0\}$.
2. For $k = 2 \delta$ one can take $A = \{\sum a_n x^n | a_{2i - 1} = 0 \text{ for } i = 1, \dotsc, \delta\}$. Here the gaps could also be taken bigger, i.e. $A = \{\sum a_n x^n | a_{3i - 1} = a_{3i-2} = 0\}$.
3. One can also mix 1. and 2:
   $ A = \{\sum a_n x^n | a_1 = \dotsc = a_5 = a_7 = 0\}$. So here $k = 8 = \delta + 2$.

All examples I found are of the type $a_i = 0$ for certain $i$, but the $i$ cannot be taken arbitrarily. For example $\{a_1 = a_4 = 0\}$ does not define an *algebra*.

**Q:** Are there examples for $A$ where the linear equations are different? If not, is there a general principle which $a_i$ can be taken to vanish?

Comment: @reuns The ring of convergent power series. Though I think the same discussion should work for formal power series.

Comment: You mean convergent on some arbitrary small disk?

Comment: @reuns Not a fixed disk. Just all formal power series with positive radius of convergence (which may depend on the power series).

Comment: Why is $\mathfrak{m}^k \subset A$ again? If so then you are searching for the $\Bbb{C}$-subalgebras of $\Bbb{C}[x]/(x^k)$, try with $k=4, span(1,x^2+x^3)$, it doesn't contain $x^2$ so it is not of the form $a_i=0$ (and we get uncountably many subalgebras of "index" $2$).

Comment: Up to isomorphism I don't know.